# Howto send credentials to RESTful service across HTTPS

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, authorization, token

So i got two sensitive informations (Apikey (For authentication) and username (authorization)) which i want to send to my Swagger generated Webservice across a secured (HTTPS) connection.

Now afaik there are several ways of doing this, some of theam are:

For instance, put them in the Header or put them in a Token and send the Token also in Header or per POST in the requests body.

My current design is:

```
//serverurl/resources
//POST 
public Response createResourceById(NewResource newResource)

//serverurl/resources/{id}
//GET
public Response getResourceById(String id)

//serverurl/resources/
//GET 
public Response getResources()
```

I would like to have my Method heads unchanged if its possible. But if i had to add the Token or the data as method paramaters it would be also ok. Like this:

```
public Response createResourceById(NewResource newResource, String apikey, String user)

public Response getResources(String apiKey, String user)
```

What would be the recommended method for sending these informations to the Webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't metter and depends on waht you are doing or what your designe requires.
Both is as secure as the other. Because both ways the data is secured over your https transport.

Comment: nope ;) In all my stuff I prefere to do authorization etc. in the header to keep my body clean.

Comment: i have updated my question a bit, does this change your response?

Comment: No it would't. How you place this data in the request is an other question ;)  When you wan't changing your API then use other mechanics to add the headers. Normaly you would impl. the auth. token handling in a filter or wrapper for all your requests to the server.